# How to read and understand the paper faisceaux pervers [BBD]

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am trying to understand the paper faisceaux pervers . As I don’t know French so I find the paper very difficult. I have started learning French. But it will be great help if someone has the English version of this paper or is aware of some reading group working in this area?
Thanks

Comment: Even working in your native language, this can be literally a whole semester-long graduate course. For instance [these notes](https://web.math.princeton.edu/~takumim/MATH731.pdf) of Takumi Murayama on a [course](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~bhattb/teaching/mat731f15/) taught by Bhargav Bhatt. [Akhil Mathew](https://amathew.wordpress.com/2011/06/23/trying-to-understand-bbd/) also has some blog posts up about it. Did you check any of these out (or do any other searching of your own) before posting this question?

Comment: Yes , I have read Akhil’s Mathew blog post . He describes about t-structure and its heart.

Comment: I can translate you, say, the first page in order you can estimate the balance of difficulty related to French language vs. intrinsic difficulty of the paper (as commented by @KReiser).

Comment: I have read t- structures from BBD . Now I want to learn recollement of t structure. I wanted help in this , that’s why I posted this question.@KReiser

Comment: Adding more information in your question about what you've done so far and where you've looked for help will make it less likely you get comments or answers telling you things you already know and more likely that you get help targeted at your specific issue. Please consider making an [edit] to add that information to your post and please keep this in mind for future questions on MSE.